# Applying multiple background images with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a grid button people can click to apply a grid over a "canvas" area (nothing to do with the CSS3 canvas). The button handler is shown below but it's not working.

When we arrive, the canvas can either have a background color and no image, or it can have an image background.  In either case we need to leave with the grid image - images/snapGrid2.gif - on top.

```
$("#grid_button").click(function(e) { 
var bgc = $('#canvas').css('background-color');
var bgi = $('#canvas').css('background-image');
if(bgi == 'none') {
    $('#canvas').css({'background' : bgc + 'url(images/snapGrid2.gif) left top'});
}
else {
    $('#canvas').css({'background' : "bgi + ',url(images/snapGrid2.gif) left top'"});
}
});
```

The first if-clause is the simpler: there's no background image on the canvas so all we need to do is create a css-background statement that includes the existing color and adds the grid. That works fine.

In the second case there is a background image so we want to create a css-background call that applies the existing image  and then the grid image. I think what I have is basically on the right track but the quotes are tripping me up.

Does someone see the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

```
$("#grid_button").click(function (e) {
    var bgc = $('#canvas').css('background-color');
    var bgi = $('#canvas').css('background-image');
    if (bgi == 'none') {
        $('#canvas').css({
            'background': bgc + 'url(images/snapGrid2.gif) left top'
        });
        bgi = $('#canvas').css('background-image');
    } else {
        $('#canvas').css({
            'background': bgi + ',url(images/snapGrid2.gif) left top'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like what Arun had, except for setting bgi at the end of the if-clause.  Not sure how that could make a difference.

Comment: @Steve - Actually that is not required, I wrote this considering it is multiple if's instead of if-else